# Equation shown as nonexistent picture with tex4ebook

Tags: equations, ebook, tex4ebook

I successfully compiled a tex source using `tex4ebook`, but none of the equations (`\begin{equation}`) are shown properly:

- In Calibre Viewer, I get a blue question mark, the one for "file not found". In fact, the `epub` source refers to a nonexistent `png`.
- On my Kindle, I see nothing.

The html file shows equations correctly in Firefox. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post minimal working example and exact command you use for compilation?

Comment: I use simply `tex4ebook mainfile.tex`. The project is here http://tempsend.com/B82481ECA4 . If you see chapter 3.7.2 there are plenty of examples

Comment: it works for me: http://tempsend.com/3EA34ED813 don't you get some error messages in the terminal output?

Comment: Actually I get a lot. There are warnings about size of graphic, others about the png files of equations which are not found. Here the log: http://pastebin.com/rw0AYh66

Comment: you've already found the issue, `dvipng` command is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package is missing: `sudo apt-get install dvipng` solves the problem. The package `dvipng` was missing