# Tex4ebook not generating SVG files

Tags: tex4ht, svg, tex4ebook

I followed the instructions in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235423/the-best-way-for-math-in-epub-font-or-svg-tex4ebook/235472#235472) to generate an ePub from Latex with SVG images(I don't want to use ePub 3.0) with `tex4ebook`, but **the generated epub has no images**.

I already found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232579/equation-shown-as-non-existing-picture-with-tex4ebook) and I have the package `dvisvgm`.
But I still have the same problem.

This is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\title{Calculus}
\author{Anon}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Chapter title} 
Expression: $\int x^2  dx$
\end{document}
```

The configuration file, `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align,pic-m,}
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
  \makeatletter
  \Configure{graphics*}
  {svg}
  {
    {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
    \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg
            \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}
  }
  \begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
```

And I've tried with and without the `.mk4` file mentioned in the previous question but I get the same result.

I use the command `tex4ebook -c myconfig.cfg tex4htExample.tex`

[This is the `.log` file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pvoun1razig3s4/tex4htExample.log?dl=0) and [the terminal output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzyqqqhyuvdvuyn/output.txt?dl=0). I can't find the missing package or error.

### Edit:

Installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine and installed Texlive with `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` and I installed `tex4ebook`. I ran the same command and I had no errors, but the result still has not any SVG file. I've opened the ePub in iBooks, Sigil and Adobe Digital Editions and all of them shows no image(or non existing image) where the expression is supposed to be.

This are the files after calling tex4ebook:

```
content.opf            tex4htExample.css   tex4htExample.log
efficient.mk4          tex4htExample.dvi   tex4htExample.ncx
myconfig.cfg           tex4htExample-epub  tex4htExample.tex
tex4htExample.4ct      tex4htExample.epub  tex4htExample.tex~
tex4htExample.4tc      tex4htExample.html  tex4htExample.tmp
tex4htExample.aux      tex4htExample.idv   tex4htExample.xref
tex4htExamplech1.html  tex4htExample.lg    zztex4htExample.ps
```

In the source code of the epub I can see it's trying to print the image `tex4htExample0x.svg`, but this doesn't exists.

If I run the command saving the output like this:

`tex4ebook -c myconfig.cfg tex4htExample.tex > linuxterminal.log`

On Linux, I get this output on the screen but not in `linuxterminal.log`:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.10.31:1458' -> 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb>[1] 
sh: 1: convert: not found
This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.10.31:1458' -> 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>[2] 
sh: 1: convert: not found
cp: cannot stat 'tex4htExample0x.svg': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'tex4htExample1x.svg': No such file or directory
```

And a slightly different one on Mac:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2015.10.31:1505' -> 
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb>
[1] 
pstoedit: version 3.62 / DLL interface 108 (built: Feb 20 2015 - release build - g++ 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) - 64-bit) : Copyright (C) 1993 - 2013 Wolfgang Glunz
Problem during opening /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.0.so:dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.0.so, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.0.so
  Reason: image not found
Problem during opening of pstoedit driver plugin: /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.0.so. This is no problem as long the driver in this library is not needed. Possibly you need to install further libraries and/or extend the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (*nix) or PATH (Windows) environment variables.
Problem during opening /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.so:dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.so, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.so
  Reason: image not found
Problem during opening of pstoedit driver plugin: /usr/local/Cellar/pstoedit/3.62_1/lib/pstoedit/libp2edrvmagick++.so. This is no problem as long the driver in this library is not needed. Possibly you need to install further libraries and/or extend the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (*nix) or PATH (Windows) environment variables.
cp: tex4htExample0x.svg: No such file or directory
```

I actually have no idea if this is relevant. Trying to find some clue.

And, just in case, [the terminal output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sy35fwgivt4ni5z/linuxterminal.log?dl=0).

Comment: the second linked question deals with `png` pictures. in your case, you need `dvisvgm` command. can you run it from the command line? could you also attach the terminal output? (not the log file, it doesn't contain possible error messages from `make4ht`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @michal.h21. Terminal output attached. And yes, I can run `dvisvgm`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, but it seems that you have also file `myconfig.cfg.tex`, which is included instead of `myconfig.cfg`. try to remove this file

Comment: You're right. I selected the option for always showing extensions on Mac and I renamed them and the error disappeared. The SVG files are not been created though. I just updated the question.

Comment: On Linux, install `imagemagick`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGaborit, I just did it and it worked. But each SVG weights 72MB!! :S

Comment: you don't use the `mk4` file. you need to use the `-e` option if it isn't named as your tex file. like `tex4ebook -c myconfig.cfg -e efficient.mk4  tex4htExample.tex`

Comment: Thank you, @michal.h21! It finally worked on Ubuntu. Now I will try to configure it in the raspberry Pi, but that will be a topic for a different question or directly on GitHub ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've got some errors related to `graphicx` package when I executed your sample. It happened because some internal `graphicx` macros are used in the `.cfg` file. Inclusion of `graphicx` package helped.

The modified file looks like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\title{Calculus}
\author{Anon}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Chapter title} 

Expression: $\int x^2  dx$
\end{document}
```

note also blank line after `\chapter`, for some reason paragraph wasn't created here, which resulted in non-valid e-pub file. So we make explicit paragraph here.

Using the `.mk4` file from the linked question, I've got correct result:

[image]

Comment: Not working for me with those changes. e-Pub resulting with no images :/

Comment: @Danowsky and do you see image in `tex4htExamplech1.html`? It is also possible that your ePub viewer doesn't support `svg` images

Comment: No, I don't see it either in the `.html`. Actually, I opened the ePub with Sigil in addition to my ePub viewer.

Comment: are you doing this in Linux? I use Mac, but I don't know if that can be related.

Comment: In `output.txt` (line 336) looks like a message from `Make4ht`: `Unsupported output format svg`

Comment: @Danowsky the message comes in fact from t4ht and it is really strange, I haven't seen it on Linux or Windows. From the log it seems that `.mk4` file isn't used, because `t4ht` wouldn't be used in that case.

Comment: Currently trying to install it in my Raspberry Pi to keep trying. It's the only Linux system I have access :/